# Numbers only in Xpages editbox?

Tags: xpages

Is there an easy way to force users to enter numbers only in a Xpages editbox?   Other than validating  the field after the fact that is.  I don't want them to be able to enter a number at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You write below code in a Xpages editbox on event onkeypress

```
if  (event.keyCode >= 48 && event.keyCode <= 57)
{
    event.returnValue = true;
}
else
{
    event.returnValue = false;
}
```

This code will force user to enter numbers only.

Answer (score 4):

You can add client-side Javascript handling such as what has been suggested here:
[HTML Text Input allow only Numeric input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469357/html-text-input-allow-only-numeric-input)

Answer (score 1):

You can add validation and formatting of numbers using the built in dojo.number class: http://dojotoolkit.org/api/1.6/dojo/number/format and make use of the dojo.form widgets.

If you're running on a mobile web platform (iOS or Android) then you should also think about setting the type of the field to number so that the platform itself will add another level of protection.

Matt

Answer (score 0):

extlib / upgrade pack1 has editors with formatting rules.